# Getting Computer information using Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Is it possible to retrieve computer information (RAM, hard drive size, cpu speed, etc.) using Adobe Flash?  If so, can someone point me to a web site showing me how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can get RAM, hard disk size, or clock speed — Flash runs in a virtual machine, and it's probably set up to only give you information that pertains to its little world.

You can get a lot of other client information, such as how much RAM Flash is using, screen resolution, and whether the client has audio support. Check out the [`System`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/System.html) and [`Capabilities`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/Capabilities.html) classes.

Comment: That's right. For security reasons you won't get more informations about the system, as these provided in those two classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some idea of the client running this, you could also try to develop your own kinda "benchmark algorthme" and run it for a second or two.

My idea for this would be to do some "hidden rendering" in a loop or something combined with a timer and a "onFrame" counter. This way I could have a rough estimate on how many loops my algorithme would run thru.

It's not perfect I know, but I believe this approach would give a rough result which could help you decide what detail level your application should provide as default and then perhaps let the user decide in a preference/settings style too.