# Request system information on a web page

Tags: javascript, flash, browser, operating-system

I need to get system information (OS system name, logged on user name etc.) about the machine where web browser is running. Is it possible using JavaScript or Flash? Silverligth, Java?

Comment: JavaScript can provide you only the OS name and details about the web browser (user agent string). To get more info about the client's computer you need to use 3rd side components aka Flash, Silverlight, Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that you can get OS name by using Capabilities class. You need to add import:

```
import flash.system.Capabilities;
```

And than you can get OS name by such code:

```
var osName:String = Capabilities.os;
```

I think with flash you won't be able to get much more information about computer due to security restrictions and because flash runs in virtual machine. You can find a bit more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/853125/2496933).

Answer (score 0):

You could get information about the OS, you could look at the user agent string. Type this into the browser console to see it

```
navigator.userAgent
```

To see the logged in username, that's a bit trickier. If you're using IIS you might want to look into [NTLM](http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html) which allows you to authenticate a web page with a windows domain controller.